# Calling event on JQuery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, observer-pattern

I have a full ajax application. Many buttons and textfields trigger `$.post` methods. Now, what I want to do is to check every `post's` method result and if this object has `success` field set to false, I want to execute `some_method` method. What is the best way to do it? I don't want to do this check in every function where I use `post` method. Is it possible to create some observer which gets triggered on every `post` method's success? Thank you.

Comment: You mean like the [global Ajax event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ajaxSuccess()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) global event handler

> Attach a function to be executed whenever an Ajax request completes
>   successfully

Ex:

```
$('body').ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, options) {
    if (xhr.responseText 
        && options.dataType == "json") {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText );
        //custom
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, request, settings) {
  if (settings.type == "POST") {
   console.log("Post success :D");
  }
});

$.post(url, function(data) {
 console.log("Success return: " + data);
}).fail(function(e) {
 console.log("Error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: The question is how to execute a particular function whenever any `$.post()` anywhere on the page succeeds. OP explicitly said "I don't want to do this check in every function where I use post method."

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/#ajaxSuccess-handlerevent--XMLHttpRequest--ajaxOptions) global event handler and add some logic to prevent executing both callbacks:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  if ( !settings.success ) {
    //The ajax request does not have a success callback
  }
});
```

Or you have to change every post call to set the parameter `global` to `false` to prevent the global handlers from being triggered.